# SqlBulkCopy - External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to use SqlBulkCopy as per the example in *[Import Excel Spreadsheet Data into SQL Server Database Table Using SqlBulkCopy](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/31/2976.aspx)*.

I've created the table and Excel sheet OK and done the coding, but I keep getting

> External table is not in the expected format.

at the `connection.open()` line.

How do I get rid of this problem?

```
    // Connection String to Excel Workbook
    String savePath = @"C:\TEMP\";

    String fileName = "upload.xls";
    savePath += fileName;
    //newpath += fileName;
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

    string excelConnectionString =
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        "Data    Source=" + savePath + ";" +
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

    // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select ID,Data FROM [Data$]", connection);

        connection.Open();

        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // SQL Server Connection String
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=GRACC011334\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ComputerBroadcastNetwork;Integrated Security=True";

            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelData";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show some code. Where do you create the connection? Where do you create the SBC object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I had to change the format of the connection string and changed it to

```
string excelConnectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=C:\TEMP\Book1.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'");
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was caused by trying to bulk copy from a spreadsheet in the newer .xlsx file format.  After I converted the spreadsheet to the older .xls format, then I was able to do teh copy without receiving the error.

I am using the same connection string that you specified above, with

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and Extended Properties=Excel 8.0

So apparently .xlsx files need different Provider and/or Extended Properties